# Accessing JSON with restangular or $resource in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework, restangular

I have done all the reading I could, but I am missing something to use AngularJS with the Django Rest framework. To solve the "trailing slash" issue, I am using restangular. The relevant parts of my module:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngResource', 'djangoRESTResources', 'restangular']);

demoApp.config(function($httpProvider){
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

demoApp.factory('CbgenRestangular', function(Restangular) {
return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:1234');
});
});

demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope, simpleFactory, CbgenRestangular, $location){

var lCems = CbgenRestangular.all("cemeteries/");

   $scope.cemeteries = lCems.getList().then(function(cemeteries) {
      console.log(cemeteries[0]);
   }, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
   });
```

TcpMon seems to show the correct response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2013 18:47:04 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
Vary: Accept, Cookie
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

[{"id": 2, "name": "Trinity Anglican New", "latitude": "N 46 14.041", "longitude": "W 060 13.170", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:1234/cemeteries/2/", "api_url": "#/cemeteries/2"}, {"id": 3, "name": "St. John's Anglican New", "latitude": "N 45 30.697", "longitude": "W 061 01.125", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:1234/cemeteries/3/", "api_url": "#/cemeteries/3"}, {"id": 4, "name": "Holy Rosary", "latitude": "N 46 03.139", "longitude": "W 060 48.479", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:1234/cemeteries/4/", "api_url": "#/cemeteries/4"}]
```

But how do I access it? This code doesn't work in my view:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cem in cemeteries | filter:filter.name">{{ cem.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Do I need to manually parse the json? If yes, how? Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Phil

Comment: Check out my seed [Angularjs/Django-Rest-Framework](https://github.com/zackargyle/angularjs-django-rest-framework-seed). It has everything set up for working with django rest. I'm sure it would help.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use it, but it failed with `DatabaseError: no such table: authtoken_token`. I do not know Fabric, so I am not sure what steps to take next.

Comment: Hey Philippe, at what point did it give you that error? It looks like you probably need to run "python manage.py migrate". Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Zack, that did it. However, I am too much of a beginner to understand really well what is happening in the services.js file. It obviously works now, but I am not sure how I can apply it to my application.

Comment: Oh I understand, that portion looks a little intense. All it does, is creates resource objects out of your "endpoints" from constants.js, that way you can say User.query() and get all the Users from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Do assignment in the callback function.

```
   lCems.getList().then(function(cemeteries) {
      //when successful
      $scope.cemeteries = cemeteries;
   }, function(response) {
      //when failed
      console.log(response);
   });
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem seems to be that the promise is failing. I.e. I can see the response object in the console, but the assignment never happens.

Comment: @Philippe Looks like `CbgenRestangular` is not correctly injected.

Comment: Would you kindly suggest a strategy to troubleshoot this issue? I cannot see anything obvious in my code above to explain why it would not be injected properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This line of code `demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope, simpleFactory, CbgenRestangular, $location)`, I assume you know how to inject the services. Obviously they don't match. And where did you define `CbgenRestangular`? Why you think Angularjs know how to interpret `CbgenRestangular`?

Comment: Isn't this part defining the service? `demoApp.factory('CbgenRestangular', function(Restangular) {
            return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
                RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8000');
            });
        });`

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue. After adding the django-cors-headers app to the Django rest framework, it worked fine.